# Will implicit orders be removed if no longer necessary?

Tags: openttd

I was tinkering with a rail junction, and then quickly saw it wasn't working. I fixed my junction, but then I was reviewing a particular train and noticed that it had several '(implicit)' orders; because it had to find a way to its final destination and I had broken the efficient route.

My question: Now that I've fixed the junction, will this train (and many others!) continue to follow their very inefficient 'Go To' orders which contain several 'implicit' instances? Or, will the pathfinding system recognize a better method exists and remove the 'implicit' orders?

I'm just dreading opening every train's go to orders on that route and verifying them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pathfinding system will remove the stops according to the [official wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Automatic_Orders).

They way they currently work is basically that they're just a user interface feature and are not taken into account when trying to find a path.